# 2D Movement simulation in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I need to make a simulation for this problem:

> Two robots A and B are placed in 2D coordinate plane, A is placed on coordinates (0,0) and B is placed on (10,0). They can make step up, down, left or right with same probability. They start moving at the same time and I need to find after how many steps they will meet. If they make more than 15000 step it is considered that they are lost and will never meet. Robots have met if they are in the same square with side 1(Example coordinates (0,0)-(1,0); (0,0)-(0,0); (0,0)-(1,1))

Now i need to make both graphical simulation and count steps until they meet in R statistical software. I have some idea how to count steps, but I'm really stuck with the graphical simulation.

Comment: Looks like homework.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes it is homework, we have some manual for R, but it contains only few commands for drawing graphs, I was hopping that there is some simple command that will allow me to draw small lines with distance 1.

Comment: I removed the Rcpp tag as there is no relationship to Rcpp as best as I can tell.

Comment: This was also cross-posted: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/51861-2D-Movement-simulation-in-R

Comment: I posted it there, is it forbidden to post same problem on two different places? I can delete thread from talkstats if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this helps? :

```
#basic plot
plot(NULL, ann = F, xlim = c(-10,20), ylim = c(-10,20))
abline(h = -10:20, col = grey(0.75), lty = 2)
abline(v = -10:20, col = grey(0.75), lty = 2)

#starting coordinates
A_coords = c(0,0)
B_coords = c(10,0)
text(A_coords[1], A_coords[2], "A", col = "red")
text(B_coords[1], B_coords[2], "B", col = "blue")

for(i in 1:15000)
 {
  Sys.sleep(1)

  text(A_coords[1], A_coords[2], "A", col = "white")
  text(B_coords[1], B_coords[2], "B", col = "white")
                                                       #used jonas's idea
  A <- A_coords + unlist(sample(list(c(0, 1), c(1, 0), c(-1, 0), c(0, -1)), 1)) 
  B <- B_coords + unlist(sample(list(c(0, 1), c(1, 0), c(-1, 0), c(0, -1)), 1))

  lines(c(A_coords[1], A[1]), c(A_coords[2], A[2]), col = "red")
  lines(c(B_coords[1], B[1]), c(B_coords[2], B[2]), col = "blue")

  A_coords <- A
  B_coords <- B

  text(A_coords[1], A_coords[2], "A", col = "red")
  text(B_coords[1], B_coords[2], "B", col = "blue")

  if(all(abs(A_coords - B_coords) <= 1)) break
 }

list(steps = i, A_coordinates = A_coords, B_coordinates = B_coords)
```

Comment: This is close to what i want. Robot need to move only up,down,left or right in each iteration, but i can fix that. My question is how to get connected lines instead of letters, when the robot is moving?

And is there any way to speed up the simulation, because 15000 steps would take long time, and I have to make 1000 simulations(without plot) :(

Comment: @LeetzMKD: You want lines to connect the path each robot is taking? In case, though, the robot moves in the opposite direction to its previous move, you'll lose part of the path. Also, if you remove `Sys.sleep` it will speed up.

Comment: if you run this simulation you will see that it is creating letters through the path, I want instead of letters to get lines. And if the robot moves the opposite direction to its previous move wouldn't the line overlap and not disappear?

Comment: @LeetzMKD: Oh, I see. You mean, instead of letter, a different symbol to be used. I can't get, though, what you mean by "line"; how to present a line with one pair of coordinates? E.g. how would you plot a line of B `c(10, 0)`?

Comment: I mean something like this [Example](http://imgur.com/qsn5Cyl), how can this be done in R?

Comment: Edit: I've used arrows(), to get the path. I think that is the best solution, considering that paths often overlap...

Comment: @LeetzMKD: I'm having a hard time erasing previously taken path at the moment, but I modified the answer a bit.  EDIT: OK, glad you found a way through this! If you want, you can post your answer and select yours as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like that:

```
plot_robots <- function(rob1, rob2){
  plot(1, xlim = c(-20, 20), ylim =c(-20, 20), type = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
  abline(h =-20:20, v = -20:20)
  points(c(rob1[1], rob2[1]), c(rob2[2], rob2[2]), pch = 21, cex = 2, bg = c("red", "blue"))
}

rob1 <- c(0, 0)
rob2 <- c(10, 0)

plot_robots(rob1, rob2)

for(i in 1:15000){
 rob1 <- rob1 + sample(list(c(0, 1), c(1, 0), c(-1, 0), c(0, -1)), 1)[[1]]
 rob2 <- rob2 + sample(list(c(0, 1), c(1, 0), c(-1, 0), c(0, -1)), 1)[[1]]
 plot_robots(rob1, rob2)
 Sys.sleep(.1)
}
```

It is not perfect but should give an idea... I don't think anybody has got the time to watch the robots until they meet. It will take ages...